# How to get tags on current commit

Tags: git

I have a repository which has multiple tags on the same commit. For example:

```
commit #3 <--- TAG1 / TAG2 / TAG3

  |

commit #2 <--- TAG4/ TAG5

  |

commit #1 <--- TAG6/ TAG7
```

I'd like to find out what tags are on a particular commit. For example, if I check commit 1, I'd like to get tag 6 and tag 7.

I have tried:

```
git checkout <commit 1> 
git tag --contains
```

which displayed tags 1-7.

```
git checkout <commit 1>
git describe --tags HEAD
```

displayed tag 6 only.

What is the proper way to do this in Git?

Answer (score 213):

For completion (thanks to Ciro Santili answer), `git tag` has got the option `--points-at` that does exactly what OP is asking.

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

It does not have the effect of also listing the tags put on forward commits (as Jonathan Hartley stated in his comment regarding `git tag --contains`).

Comment: This is the best answer here. No complicated command line needed, but gives just the tag name.

Comment: From `git help tag`: `--points-at <object> – Only list tags of the given object (HEAD if not specified). Implies --list.`. So `-l` and `HEAD` can be omitted.

Comment: @fphilipe Thanks. I suggested an edit without the -l. Removing HEAD would make the command ambiguous.

Comment: @AalexGabi - How would removing `HEAD` make the command ambiguous?

Comment: @ijoseph - What do you mean by "nested tags"?

Comment: @friederbluemle tag of another tag, rather than of a commit itself; it's [subtly different. See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049470/588437).

Comment: @friederbluemle HEAD is an explicit reference for --points-at. If not specified it's not clear (for someone reading the answer) for what commit tags are listed.

Comment: @AalexGabi I understand it's an explicit reference. However there is nothing _ambiguous_ about omitting it. Like many other commands (e.g. `git branch`, `git reset`, etc), it **defaults to HEAD**. The comment about ambiguity had me double check the man page if there was something unexpected with the `tag --contains` command. It turned out there isn't, so `HEAD` is _not_ required, and in most scenarios does not need to be specified.

Answer (score 28):

I guess maybe git has had some options added since this question was asked, but since it still comes in pretty high on google, I thought I'd add that this way works nicely:

```
git tag -l --contains HEAD
```

Or replace `HEAD` with any other valid commit reference you like.

This will print a newline separated list of tags if the HEAD contains any tags, and print nothing otherwise, so you would get:

```
TAG6
TAG7
```

And of course there are lots of nice ways with various other shell tools that you can format that output once you have it...

Comment: Works perfectly. Just why do you need `-l`? From the manual it seems that `-l` without args lists all tags, which is the same as `tag` without arguments.

Comment: @cirosantilli oops, I guess I didn't read the manual carefully enough.  Though I think I like adding the `-l` because it makes sure I don't end up adding a new tag if I forget the `--contains` flag.

Comment: This gives the wrong output. It shows all tags that 'contain' the given commit, i.e. tags applied to previous reachable commits are also included. The original question explicitly says he doesn't want these old tags, only the 'current' tags ON the given commit.

Answer (score 18):

Some improvements on William's answer:

```
git config --global alias.tags 'log -n1 --pretty=format:%h%d'
```

The output looks like this:

```
~$ git tags
7e5eb8f (HEAD, origin/next, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
~$ git tags HEAD~6
e923eae (tag: v1.7.0)
```

Comment: I'm trying to add sed/tr/grep commands to convert this output into a plain list with no punctuation. I can construct such a 'git log' command directly, but the escaping is killing me when I put it into a git config alias. Here's my log command: git log -n1 --pretty="format:%d" | sed "s/, /\n/g" | grep tag | sed "s/tag: \|)//g"

Comment: I've refined this to make it more useful to automated scripts (e.g putting the tags into your prompt), in an answer below...

Answer (score 12):

`git tag --points-at`

> --points-at
>
> Only list tags of the given object (HEAD if not specified). Implies --list.

from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

Answer (score 6):

This is not ideal, but perhaps helpful:

```
$ git log -n 1 --decorate --pretty=oneline
```

You could play around with the format to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your info , my repo has more than 300 different gits. Press  "Q" for 300 time really hard for me .

Comment: Whenever I using git log to display anything , I need press q button to exit the log display mode . Not sure if you facing the same

Answer (score 5):

This displays the commit id of HEAD, as well as any branches or any tags that also happen to be exactly at HEAD.

```
git reflog --decorate -1
```

Sample output:

```
484c27b (HEAD, tag: deployment-2014-07-30-2359, master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: 484c27b878ca5ab45185267f4a6b56f8f8d39892: updating HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a refinement of @JoshLee's answer, which manipulates the output to list only tags (not branches, nor HEAD) and strips the word 'tag:' and decorative punctuation. This is useful if you are scripting something up which needs to find the current tags (e.g. put them in your prompt):

```
git log -n1 --pretty="format:%d" | sed "s/, /\n/g" | grep tag: | sed "s/tag: \|)//g"
```

Example output:

```
$ git log -n 1 --decorate=short
commit a9313...c7f2 (HEAD, tag: v1.0.1, tag: uat, mybranch)
...
$ git log -n1 --pretty="format:%d" | sed "s/, /\n/g" | grep tag: | sed "s/tag: \|)//g"
v1.0.1
uat
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I had to modify the last `sed` command because it was not stripping the 'tag: ' string for me, maybe because my tags have levels, like `internal/variant/version`.
If anyone has the same issue, here's the modified script:
`git log -n1 --pretty="format:%d" | sed "s/, /\n/g" | grep tag: | sed 's/tag: //'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `git tag --points-at HEAD`, make sure to use  Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

"[`git tag --list --points-at X`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5929e66755acc797b2612d8d6d6b6fd6e7759169/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L100)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---list))</sup> showed tags that directly refers to object `X`, but did not list a tag that points at such a tag, which has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit d9e0062](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9e00621591549cd2d9989d290a7e0c63eadd03b), [commit 870eb53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/870eb53ab20e9ff453e3b89b4927c154c2b7211a), [commit b9584c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9584c5858799d5603851af5f0dbad5e7af29b22) (02 Jul 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 468887f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/468887f0f8a0a9e465737c3ad23cb40c8d690f2f) (01 Jul 2023) by [Jan Klötzke (`jkloetzke`)](https://github.com/jkloetzke).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5929e66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5929e66755acc797b2612d8d6d6b6fd6e7759169), 25 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/468887f0f8a0a9e465737c3ad23cb40c8d690f2f): handle nested tags in --points-at option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jan Klötzke</sup>

> Tags are dereferenced until reaching a different object type to handle nested tags, e.g. on checkout.
> In contrast, "[`git tag --points-at=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468887f0f8a0a9e465737c3ad23cb40c8d690f2f/Documentation/git-tag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> fails to list such nested tags because only one level of indirection is obtained in `filter_refs()`.
>
> Implement the recursive dereferencing for the "`--points-at`" option when filtering refs to unify the behaviour.

That will list nested tag, and that will do it faster:

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9584c5858799d5603851af5f0dbad5e7af29b22): avoid parsing tagged objects in `match_points_at()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When we peel tags to check if they match a `--points-at` oid, we recursively parse the tagged object to see if it is also a tag.
> But since the tag itself tells us the type of the object it points to (and even gives us the appropriate object struct via its "tagged" member), we can use that directly.
>
> We do still have to make sure to call `parse_tag()` before looking at each tag.
> This is redundant for the outermost tag (since we did call `parse_object()` to find its type), but that's OK; `parse_tag()` is smart enough to make this a noop when the tag has already been parsed.
>
> In my clone of linux.git, with 782 tags (and only 3 non-tags), this yields a significant speedup (bringing us back where we were before the commit before this one started recursively dereferencing tags):
>
> ```
> Benchmark 1: ./git.old for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname)"
>   Time (mean ± σ):      20.3 ms ±   0.5 ms    [User: 11.1 ms, System: 9.1 ms]
>   Range (min … max):    19.6 ms …  21.5 ms    141 runs
>
> Benchmark 2: ./git.new for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname)"
>   Time (mean ± σ):      11.4 ms ±   0.2 ms    [User: 6.3 ms, System: 5.0 ms]
>   Range (min … max):    11.0 ms …  12.2 ms    250 runs
>
> Summary
>   './git.new for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname)"' ran
>     1.79 ± 0.05 times faster than './git.old for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname)"'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing `git tag -l | grep $(git describe HEAD)`
it returns the tag of the latest commit, or nothing if the last commit isn't tagged