# Git tag another tag

Tags: git, git-tag

How can I put a tag on same references of another tag?
For example I would like to put tag "Stable_Build" on a tag of a certain release "1.0.0.1".

Is there a better\faster way to do it except to:

```
git checkout 1.0.0.1
git tag -a Stable_Build
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go with `git tag <new_tag> <old_tag>` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))

```
$ git tag stable 1.0.0

$ git tag --list
1.0.0
stable
```

By the way: it would not refer to tag 1.0.0 but to same commit as tag 1.0.0.

Comment: Also consider `git tag new_tag old_tag^{commit}` if the existing tag is annotated and you want your new (lightweight) tag to point directly to the commit, rather than to the other annotated tag object. Similarly, if you're going to make a new annotated tag, consider `git tag -a new_tag old_tag^{commit}`. The `^{commit}` suffix says *resolve the old tag to a commit hash ID*, which `git checkout` would do automatically.

Answer (score 7):

`git tag new_tag old_tag` is problematic if the old tag is annotated, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578341/git-tag-another-tag/56049470#comment94029394_53578785).

This was [illustrated on the Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAHd499BM91tf7f8=phR4Az8vMsHAHUGYsSb1x9as=WukUVZHJw@mail.gmail.com/) by Robert Dailey.

And this is why Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) will warn you, giving an advice suggesting it might be a mistake when creating an annotated or signed tag that points at another tag.

See [commit eea9c1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eea9c1e78ffd878cbaaf2c1e346e186a1e58a460), [commit 01dc801](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01dc801adad35d4e2f815dc1918dad057631bc0e) (04 Apr 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff), and [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a198562](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1985623415223662a51b240e814d5f22b231830), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### tag: advise on nested tags
>
> Robert Dailey reported confusion on the mailing list about a nested tag which was most likely created by mistake.
>   Jeff King noted that this isn't a very common case and creating a tag-to-a-tag can be a user-error.
>
> Suggest that it may be a mistake with an advice message when creating such a tag.
>   Those who do want to create a tag that point at another tag regularly can turn it off with the usual advice mechanism.

You will now see, when tagging a tag (nested tagging):

```
hint: You have created a nested tag. The object referred to by your new is
hint: already a tag. If you meant to tag the object that it points to, use:
hint: |
hint: git tag -f nested annotated-v4.0^{}
```

So, if you already did:

```
git tag stable 1.0.0
```

You can fix it with:

```
git tag -f stable 1.0.0^{}
```

There might be later a "`git tag --allow-nested-tag -f stable 1.0.0`" (if you actually *wanted* to tag the tag `1.0.0` by another annotated tag), but this is [not implemented yet](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190403213318.GA14137@dev-l/).

Comment: "`git tag new_tag old_tag` is problematic" -- what specifically is the problem? i.e. if a new unannotated tag points to an annotated tag rather than a commit, why would this cause a problem?

Comment: @ijoseph the issue is not so much the tag you are creating, but to what you are pointing to with said new tag. If the tag you are pointing to is an annotated one, you are creating a tag (annotated or not) referencing another tag(!). Most often, what you want to do when creating a tag is to reference a commit, hence the comment from torek. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578341/git-tag-another-tag/56049470#comment94029394_53578785)

Comment: This make sense and I've seen the comment above, but I'm just wondering in what practical scenarios this would be an issue. Perhaps one scenario would be: if the first (annotated) tag is deleted accidentally, the second tag is then orphaned and doesn't point to anything anymore and is thus useless? Or perhaps deleting the first tag will unexpectedly cascade to a delete of the second?

Comment: @ijoseph Deleting the first tag won't delete the second, but the second will be indeed orphan. Again, the issue is about "expectation": if you tag a tag, expecting to tag a commit, that is the problem here.